# How to remove duplicated scrollbar in Angular Covalent templates?

Tags: angular, scrollbar, teradata-covalent

*I am super new to Angular 4. I've onlçy created few projects with AngularJS.*

I started using **Teradata Covalent Framework** to build front-end structure and focus on building the menu content and card lists for a Catalog Web App.

I downloaded this full template in https://stackblitz.com/edit/covalent-dashboard-ynyp1w?file=main.ts which you can see in the image below:

[image]

As you can see, the problem is those two scrollbars in the right side of the page. I think that only the inner scroll should exist there because it is not interfering with the gray toolbar.

```
<td-layout>
  <td-navigation-drawer flex [sidenavTitle]="name" logo="assets:covalent">
    Top level navigation drawer
  </td-navigation-drawer>
  <td-layout-nav [toolbarTitle]="(media.registerQuery('gt-xs') | async) ? 'Dashboard' : ''" logo="assets:covalent" navigationRoute="/">
    <button mat-icon-button td-menu-button tdLayoutToggle>
      <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
    </button>
    <div td-toolbar-content>
      Top toolbar
    </div>
    <td-layout-manage-list #manageList>
      <div td-sidenav-content layout="column" layout-fill>
        Inner sidenav listing dashboards
      </div>

      <mat-sidenav-container flex>
        <mat-sidenav #sidenav align="end">
          Right Sidenav
        </mat-sidenav>
        <td-layout-nav>
          <div td-toolbar-content>
            Second toolbar
          </div>

          <div flex layout-gt-sm="row">
            <div flex-gt-sm="50">
              <mat-card>
                ...
              </mat-card>
            </div>
          </div>

        </td-layout-nav>
      </mat-sidenav-container>
    </td-layout-manage-list>
    <td-layout-footer>Footer content</td-layout-footer>
  </td-layout-nav>
</td-layout>
```

Anyone who already worked with this template or is very good at CSS could tell me how to remove this creep extra scrollbar from the site? And (*Bonus*) How could I replace those old scrollbar style for those new skinny scrollbars from Facebook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your page content is being wrapped in a `<mat-sidenav-container flex>` element. You'll want to use the `<td-layout-nav>` element outside of that.

I've fixed the page in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-47289859). A simplified version of the code is below.

```
<td-layout>
  <td-navigation-drawer flex [sidenavTitle]="name" logo="assets:covalent">
    Top level navigation drawer
  </td-navigation-drawer>
  <td-layout-nav [toolbarTitle]="(media.registerQuery('gt-xs') | async) ? 'Dashboard' : ''" logo="assets:covalent" navigationRoute="/">
    <button mat-icon-button td-menu-button tdLayoutToggle>
      <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
    </button>
    <div td-toolbar-content>
      Top toolbar
    </div>
    <td-layout-manage-list #manageList>
      <div td-sidenav-content layout="column" layout-fill>
        Inner sidenav listing dashboards
      </div>

      <td-layout-nav>
        <div td-toolbar-content>
          Second toolbar
        </div>

        <mat-sidenav-container flex>
          <mat-sidenav #sidenav align="end">
            Right Sidenav
          </mat-sidenav>
          <div flex layout-gt-sm="row">
            <div flex-gt-sm="50">
              <mat-card>
                ...
              </mat-card>
            </div>
          </div>

        </mat-sidenav-container>
      </td-layout-nav>
    </td-layout-manage-list>
    <td-layout-footer>Footer content</td-layout-footer>
  </td-layout-nav>
</td-layout>
```

Comment: Thank you @Chic your code fixed the issue. I am going to study the code in order to try fixing the button to hide the left sidebar. It crashes after minimizing the sidebar.

Answer (score 2):

Just add `overflow:hidden;` to the css class of the inner content